# Sending hangfire job to specific queue

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am currently using hangfire to en-queue jobs. 
The conventional way to en-queue a hangfire job is by using something like this:

```
 BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DoWork());
```

which will then intern en-queue and execute this job in the *"DEFAULT"* hangfire queue.

I can however add a attribute to the method which will intern be used to determine which queue it will be placed in and executed:

```
    [Queue("SECONDARY")]
    public void DoWork()
    {

    }
```

***My question:***
Is there a way to to dynamically/programmatically en-queue a hangfire job in a specified queue with out using the above mentioned method attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudo-code for you.

https://api.hangfire.io/html/M_Hangfire_BackgroundJobClient_Create.htm

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EnqueuedState queue = new EnqueuedState("myQueueName");
        new BackgroundJobClient().Create<Program>(c => c.DoWork(), queue);
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {

    }
}
```

The other option I am aware of is to make use of an interface and indirectly make use of the attribute. See pseudo-code below:

```
 {
     interface IHangfireJob
     {
         [Queue("secondary")]
         void Execute();
     }
 }

 class Program : IHangfireJob
 {
     static void SomeMainMethod()
     {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Execute());
     }

     public void Execute()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above code will work to queue to specific queue. But I have aproblem. Let us assume , we are having two queue default and secondary.  Suppose i queued job to the secondary queue using above method. And it got failed. When it retry . It is try to retry in default queue. But i want it to do in secondary queue. How to achieve it?

Comment: Have you considered using an interface ? See my updated answer above.
If that is not going to work for you, then i am out of ideas ;-P
Hope someone else can help you.
Good luck.

Comment: Pieter Alberts. By using interface we can achieve. As I told earlier in my question i don't want to use attribute. Because your first approach work. But when the job failed and try to retry it will come to default queue